# Detecting click on a child inside a recyclerview item (Gmail)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, click, position

How can I detect a click on a specific child in a recyclerview item? 
In the Gmail app, this is used to be able to select items really quickly without a long press, but instead just by clicking on the "contact image". 
How can I detect where the user clicks inside a specific item?

Thanks!

[image: Gmail app]

Comment: Have you tried adding a clickListener to the view you want to be clickable?

Comment: @EduardoHerzer Sounds like a good idea, thanks. Didn't thought it would be that easy ;)

Comment: no problem. Sometimes the solution is simple =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inflate a row in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` subclass, you can add a `View.OnClickListener` to any of its child views and manipulate the row from there.

```
final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);

rowView.findViewById(R.id.avatar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        rowView.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
});
```